# tf.train.write_graph can not save model when called by java

Tags: android, tensorflow, graph

in order to save trained model in mobile, i write a model as below for research.

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Session() as sess:
    def save_model():
        path = tf.train.write_graph(sess.graph_def, '/data/data/com.chelexa.tfandroid', 'mnist_50_mlp.pb',as_text=False)
        #path_folder=path[33:36]
        return tf.to_float(tf.rank(path))
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 784], name="x")
    y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10], name="y")

    W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]), name="weights")
    b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))

    y_out = tf.matmul(x, W) + b

    #cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y * tf.log(y_out), reduction_indices=[1]))
    cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y, logits=y_out))
    train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy, name="train")

    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_out,1), tf.argmax(y,1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32), name="test")

    init = tf.variables_initializer(tf.global_variables(), name="init")
    save = tf.add(1.0,save_model(),name="save_model")
    save_save = tf.add(1.0,save_model(),name="savesave")
```

then i save trained model by java

```
TensorFlowInferenceInterface.run(new String[]{"save_model"}, new String[]{}, logStats);
```

after run call can return right value save == 1, but have no mnist_50_mlp.pb file saved in my apk folder in /data/data/com.chelexa.tfandroid/

thanks!